# Execute Oracle procedure in TOAD

Tags: oracle, toad

I am writing an Oracle procedure using TOAD. I executed the procedure using execute statement. But I am not able to get the result. Instead of that am getting error only. Please help how to run the procedure in TOAD. I am new to toad and Oracle.

Procedure in oracle

```
create or replace procedure pro_dndtesting( phone number)is 
begin
select  FLD_PHONENUMBERS from smsdnd_tbl where FLD_PHONENUMBERS=phone;
end ;
/
```

Executing procedure as follows

```
exec procedure pro_dndtesting(9865015695)

error

ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00201: identifier 'PRO_DNDTESTING' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just to clarify: there is no such thing as "Oracle Toad". Oracle is a RDBMS, whereas TOAD is a client for Oracle databases.

Your procedure won't compile as you have written it because you don't give an INTO clause for the SELECT (since PL/SQL - as opposed to plain SQL - requires a "target" for the result of the SELECT); try this:

```
create or replace procedure pro_dndtesting( phone number)is 
  l_value smsdnd_tbl.fld_phonenumbers%type;
begin
  select  FLD_PHONENUMBERS 
    into l_value 
    from smsdnd_tbl 
   where FLD_PHONENUMBERS=phone;
end ;
```

As for the error you're getting:

Did you use the same schema (=user) for defining the procedure and calling it?

Did you try it from an anonymous PL/SQL block like

```
begin
  pro_dndtesting(9865015695);
end;
```